# Mouseover ,Mouseout event not firing in IE

Tags: javascript, html

Hi i have the following html layout

```
 <div id="stripe_container" style="top: 0px; border: 1px solid rgb(235, 116, 41);  
background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(243, 232, 151); position: fixed; height: 30px;  
width: 100%; left: 0px; z-index: 99999999; font-size: 14px; font-family: Verdana;   
cursor: pointer;" class="">
  <div id="stripe_rollover" style="height: 30px; background-color: transparent; z-index:  
    99999999; left: 0px; width: 97%; position: fixed;"></div>
   <div id="stripe_text_left" style="margin-top: 5px; margin-left: 15px; color: black;  
    float: left;">Text Test</div>
   <div id="stripe_text_right" style="top: 4px; right: 40px; cursor: pointer; position:  
   absolute; float: right;">Mouseover</div>
```

below is my js code

```
  <script>
  var x;
stripe_rollover.onmouseover=function(){
   x=document.createElement('div');
   x.style.height='30px';
   x.style.width='40px';
   x.style.backgroundColor='#000000';
   var stripe_container=document.getElementById('stripe_container');
   stripe_container.parentNode.insertBefore(x,stripe_container.nextSibling);
```

}

```
stripe_rollover.onmouseout=function(){
   x.parentNode.removeChild(x); 
}
```

Iam facing  an issue in IE browsers. IE 8,9 and even 10. when i mouseover the strip div , the mouseover event is fired, but when the cursor is moved on the **Mouseover** text the event is not fired.

Comment: Can u create jsfiddle for the same?

Comment: @Murali http://jsfiddle.net/xxY6b/

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem ([Example](http://jsfiddle.net/T4JBJ/1/))

```
function mouseOver_handler(){
    // ...
}

function mouseOut_handler(){
    // ...
}

stripe_rollover.onmouseover = mouseOver_handler;
stripe_text_left.onmouseover = mouseOver_handler
stripe_text_right.onmouseover = mouseOver_handler;

stripe_rollover.onmouseout = mouseOut_handler;
stripe_text_left.onmouseout = mouseOut_handler
stripe_text_right.onmouseout = mouseOut_handler;
```

Comment: but the stripe_rollover  div covers  stripe_text_left and stripe_text_right
so y shud add a handler to them. how does it work in FF, chrome